# Create custom compact layout/record preview component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, mousehover, preview

I'd like to create the functionality that occurs when hovering over a record link in Lightning Community as pictured below:

[image: Record Preview]

Is there any standard Lightning component that would achieve this, or an action that can load a specific component within this kind of container?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a standard component [lightning:overlayLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:overlayLibrary/specification)  and you can use it with the `showCustomPopover` method to show a popover.

You will have to get the record data by yourself and display it in the popover by yourself

There is another option that I use from the strike open source library: [Strike Popover](http://www.lightningstrike.io/#!/strikePopover). You will still have to get data and display it by yourself, but this component has more options, more simple, and open source so you can change it as you like

Good luck